# vb.net creating a label using a class

Tags: vb.net

I am new to using classes and OOP. I have created a class that will create a new label every time it is called. here is my code:

```
Public lbl As New Label
Public txt As New TextBox
Public controls As List(Of Control)
Public Sub New()
    'Add a label

    lbl.Name = "Label" & 1
    lbl.Text = "Student " & 1 & ":"
    lbl.Size = New Size(65, 20)
    lbl.Location = New Point(10, (10 * 22) + 5)

    controls.Add(lbl)
End Sub
```

When i call this class i get this error message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Project.exe    Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The line of code the message highlights is:

```
controls.Add(lbl)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add the new label? do you want to add it to your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public lbl As New Label
Public txt As New TextBox
Public controls As List(Of Control)

Public Sub New()
  'Add a label

  lbl.Name = "Label" & 1
  lbl.Text = "Student " & 1 & ":"
  lbl.Size = New Size(65, 20)
  lbl.Location = New Point(10, (10 * 22) + 5)
  If (controls is nothing) = True Then controls = new list(of Control)
  controls.Add(lbl)
End Sub
```

Comment: You must make sure that your controls list has been instantiated before you try to use ...  controls = new list(of Control)

Comment: when I call the class the label isn't displayed, is there something I am missing?

Comment: Maybe you can add lbl.Visible = True but i'm not sure... I should think the label needs to be added to the form from your class something along the lines of form1.controls.add(mycontrolslist(0))

Comment: The line `form1.controls.add(mycontrolslist(0))` works, thanks :)

Comment: I used 0 because the label you added is the FIRST label in your list, in reality if you want to display the LAST label added to your list.... than you should use....  form1.controls.add(mycontrolslist(mycontrolslist.count-1))